# CSS: Is it possible to have 50% of the box-shadow of a button in one color, and the other 50% in another color?

Tags: css

With the help of [this wonderful article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49620419/is-it-possible-to-make-a-blurred-gradient-shadow-with-css), I created this:

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#button {
margin-left: 20px;
margin-top: 20px;
padding: 20px;
box-shadow: 20px 0 40px blue, -20px 0 40px red;
display: inline-block;
width: 200px;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="button">Button</div>
```

But I would need something that splits the box shadow exactly in the half, like that, without any position shifts:

[image]

Here is some code to try:

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#button {
margin-left: 20px;
margin-top: 20px;
padding: 20px;
box-shadow: 0 0 30px blue;
display: inline-block;
width: 200px;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="button">Button</div>
```

Is that possible? Maybe working with two layers? It should generally look totally like it's just a simple shadow, because it will be mixed with other buttons, and only one should have two colors for the shadow. It would be weird if the shadow style is completely different. Would be very thankful for help!

Comment: I guess this is possible with JS but in my brain to avoid shadow leaking over to the other side it would at the very least take a duplicate box for the second shadow and even then I wouldn't know how to stop the shadow leaking over. But I do think two shadow colours leaking into each other can look very cool so try that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’d use an element for each half of the button that clips a box the size of the entire button with the appropriate box shadow.

```css
body {
  padding: 40px;
}

.thing {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.thing-shadow {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: calc(2 * var(--thing-shadow-radius));
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(-2 * var(--thing-shadow-radius));
  width: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.thing-shadow::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(2 * var(--thing-shadow-radius));
  top: calc(2 * var(--thing-shadow-radius));
  right: calc(2 * var(--thing-shadow-radius));
  bottom: calc(2 * var(--thing-shadow-radius));
}

.thing-shadow-left {
  left: calc(-2 * var(--thing-shadow-radius));
  padding-right: 0;
}

.thing-shadow-right {
  right: calc(-2 * var(--thing-shadow-radius));
  padding-left: 0;
}

.thing-shadow-left::before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 var(--thing-shadow-radius) var(--thing-shadow-left);
  right: calc(-1 * var(--thing-shadow-radius));
}

.thing-shadow-right::before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 var(--thing-shadow-radius) var(--thing-shadow-right);
  left: calc(-1 * var(--thing-shadow-radius));
}

#button {
  --thing-shadow-left: red;
  --thing-shadow-right: blue;
  --thing-shadow-radius: 40px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="thing" id="button">
  <span class="thing-shadow thing-shadow-left"></span>
  <span class="thing-shadow thing-shadow-right"></span>
  Button
</button>
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This can *almost* be done without additional markup, but the box-shadow on the pseudo elements will still cover the button, so an additional div is needed inside the button to give the button background color and cover the shadows inside the button.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#button {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

#button div {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#button:before,
#button:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
}

#button:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px blue;
  left: 0;
}

#button:after {
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px red;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="button">
  <div>
Button
  </div>
</div>
```